# Renovate: How to override the default fileMatch for Terraform

Tags: terraform, renovate

We are using [Renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) to update our dependencies. Unfortunately the Terraform manager updates the provider versions of modules too. We don't want this as we specify minimum versions.

I know how to exclude whole paths from the Renovate analysis (ignorePaths) and how to add further RexEx to analyze files not included in the default RexEx of the manager. But how to replace the default RegEx for fileMatch?

```
"terraform" {"override-fileMatch": "^(?!modules\/.*providers.tf).*\.tf$"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this config:

```json
{
  "terraform": {
    "fileMatch": [
      "^(?!modules\/.*providers.tf).*\.tf$"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It might also be useful to add this to your `config.js`:

    ignorePaths: ['**/modules/**/provider.tf']